# Is it possible to change bibliography style with a variable?

Tags: bibliographies, harvard-style

I am writing a thesis class and using natbib package for bibliography. But there are two options for bibliography, one is numeric and second is harvard style. I defined a variable as "thesisbibstyle" for selection as

```
\newcommand*{\thesisbibstyle}[1]{\def\@bibtype{#1}}
```

and selection is peformed in tex file by using

```
\thesisbibstyle{harvard} or \thesisbibstyle{numeric}
```

commands. In class file, i am checking the entry in tex file with code

```
\gdef\@bibhrv{harvard}
\gdef\@bibnmr{numeric}

\ifx\@bibtype\@bibhrv
    % harvard style selected
    \RequirePackage[round]{natbib}
\else
    % numeric style selected
    \RequirePackage[numbers, sort&compress]{natbib}
\fi
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

For first time compiling it's OK. But when i changed the selection from "harvard" to "numeric" or from "numeric" to "harvard", nothing changes. Why?
Or is there any other approach?

Comment: You need to clean all auxiliary files, and start the whole chain of pdflatex/bibtex/pdflatex/pdflatex once again.

Comment: Please provide a complete, compilable example. If `natbib` isn't switching between the two citation call-out styles, it may be because something is off in your code. We can't tell for sure, though, unless we see the actual code. The `natbib` citation management package -- when used with a bibliography style (e.g., `unsrtnat`) that's capable of producing both numeric-style or authoryear-style citation callouts -- should indeed allow simple switching between the two citation call-out styles. Aside: "harvard" is kind of an old-fashioned term in this context; better call the style "authoryear".

Comment: Incidentally, is there a reason for not specifying the option `authoryear` explicitly if "harvard" is selected?

Comment: @Johannes_B - If `natbib` is invoked correctly, it should *not* be necessary to go through the full recompilation cyle -- pdflatex/bibtex/pdflatex/pdflatex  -- just to switch between citaton call-out styles. Changing the package option from `authoryear` to `numbers` (or vice versa) plus a single run of pdflatex should suffice.